# How to Auto Scroll a page in #Telenium. except Drag method. The App is created in #Kivy

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation, kivy, kivymd

I am working with Kivy and writing test cases for it in `Telenium`, but unable to get any resolution for scrolling a page, i tried `drag()` method but it is not working as expected.

```
class PaymentScreen(TeleniumTestProcess):
                def test_select_subscripton(self):
                         self.cli.drag(
                                       "//NavigationItem[@text=\"Sent\"]",
                                       "//NavigationItem[@text=\"Inbox\"]", 1)
```

Is there any other method like `scroller()` for gradually scrolling the page or elements?

Answer (score 0):

Good day. I am unsure if there is a scrollview but the scrollview has a [scroll_y](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_y) property that can be set to scroll to a position.

Comment: Thankyou for response, i am writing test cases in telenium, so i need a method which can auto scroll the list.
I have used ScrollView in .kv file